# Can one force TimeSeries to add instead of average values with identical timestamps?

Tags: data, time-series

I have a list of time-value pairs of the form `{{t1,v1},{t2,v2},{t3,v3},...}` that I'd like to turn into a `TimeSeries` object.

The problem is, some of the time values are identical, meaning the list actually looks more like

`{{t1,v1},{t2,v2a},{t2,v2b},{t3,v3},...}`.

If I simply operate on the list with `TimeSeries`, Mathematica averages the values corresponding to the identical times, thus producing

`{{t1,v1},{t2,(v2a+v2b)/2},{t3,v3},...}`.

But I want it to **add** those values instead, thereby producing

`{{t1,v1},{t2,(v2a+v2b)},{t3,v3},...}`.

Alas, I can't find an option for `TimeSeries` which controls this behavior. Does anyone know if such an option exists?

If that option does not, can anyone suggest an elegant solution to combine these values before wrapping them with `TimeSeries`? I vaguely recall seeing a simple line of code to do just that somewhere here before, but I've been unable to find that, too.

Meanwhile, I'll continue working the problem myself, and I'll post any solutions I come up with.

Thanks!

----------UPDATE----------

I came up with the following workaround:

```
If[Length@# > 1, {#[[1, 1]], Total@#[[All, 2]]}, #[[1]]] & /@ 
   GatherBy[#, First] &@{{t1, v1}, {t2, v2a}, {t2, v2b}, {t3, v3}}
```

which outputs
`{{t1, v1}, {t2, v2a + v2b}, {t3, v3}}`.

I can then hit that with `TimeSeries`.

But is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This seems to be an oversight in the language design IMHO. `TimeSeries` does something undocumented (taking the average) when it encounters duplicate timestamps, instead of allowing the user to supply a function. `TimeSeriesInsert` will replace any existing value with the same timestamp, when it too could have allowed the user to supply a function.

Comment: To whom do I complain? ;-)

Comment: I [just asked about this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54908240#54908240) in the chat room :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this with TimeSeries, but you can do it yourself with `GroupBy` like this:

```
data = SortBy[First] @ Table[{RandomInteger[{0, 10}], RandomReal[]}, 20];
ts = TimeSeries[GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]]
```

Comment: Nice. I've never worked with associations before, but they seem quite useful--especially for my current project. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronEiben Definitely make sure to learn about them. They're super useful for lots of things.

Comment: Okay, I'm giving this the win since the desired option for `TimeSeries` doesn't seem to exist, and for sending me down the rabbit holes of `Association` and `Dataset`.

(Though funnily enough, these constructs might render the original need moot.)